# .NET MVC controller accepting invalid json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to stop my REST API accepting invalid json bodies in my controller.

I have a REST API which has a .NET MVC endpoint. On this endpoint we have a post method that takes a body of type customer (largely simplified in this example), the class for it is as follows:

```
 public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public List<Xref> Xrefs { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string AddressLineOne { get; set; }
    public string AddressLineTwo { get; set; }
}

public class Xref
{
    public string System { get; set; }
    public List<Segment> Segments { get; set; }

}

public class Segment
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And the method for the controller is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]Customer customer)
{
...
}
```

A valid json Representation of the body is as follows:

```
{
"FirstName": "firstName",
"LastName": "lastName",
"Addresses":
[
    {
        "AddressLineOne" : "addressLineOne",
        "AddressLineTwo" : "addressLineTwo"
    }
],
"Xrefs":[
    {
        "System":"systemOne",
        "Segments":[
            {
                "Name":"name",
                "Value":"value"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I have noticed that if I make a request to the API with invalid json, the request controller still receives the body and will disregard everything after the incorrect section. An example of this representation is below where the xrefs does not have a closing brace:

```
{
"FirstName": "firstName",
"LastName": "lastName",

"Xrefs":[
    {
        "System":"systemOne",
        "Segments":[
            {
                "Name":"name",
                "Value":"value"
            }

        ]

,
"Addresses":
[
    {
        "AddressLineOne" : "addressLineOne",
        "AddressLineTwo" : "addressLineTwo"
    }
],
}
```

What happens when this data is posted to the controller is that the customer object will contain the firstname, lastname and the xref, but will not contain the address. This is because according to the json hierarchy we are still in the xref and have not closed it off.

When creating a unit test for this functionality and attempting to DeserializeObject you encounter a JsonSerializationException but this doers not happen in the controller method.

Now I am trying to find a way to stop the invalid json being accepted in the controller. I do not want partial json deserialization in any form, either the json is valid or is not. I thought about building a validation Filter and adding it onto the HttpConfig, this filter would use reflection to find out what the intended body of the request should look like, then it would attempt to deserialize the body into it, if an exception is thrown the request won't pass.

I have held off on doing this because I assume that there is a simpler and less resource intensive way of doing this built into MVC such as a flag for allow incomplete json body but I have been unable to find it. I am also reluctant to do this in the filters as it will be extremely resource intensive to filter each request like this, especially since reflection is very taxing and we are catching an exception to try to validate. This filter would be fine in a small MVC API but this system requires extremely low response times.

If you know of any better solutions please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Use Json Schema, see http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema

Comment: and a custom model binder, where you could validate the JSON

Comment: or use string customer... you will get the JSON string, validate, and convert the json to the desired object.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use model binding validation to ensure the data by simply adding keywords to your class.

Take a look at using either a bunch of required tags:

```
public class Xref
{
    [Required]
    public string System { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<Segment> Segments { get; set; }

}
```

Or the general validate model:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateModel]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]Customer customer)
{
...
}
```

[See this for specific examples](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api)